# Relation That is Symmetric and Anti-symmetric but neither reflexive nor transitive

Tags: relations

Let $Q = \{A,B,C\}$.

I argue that a relation on A that is symmetric and Anti-symmetric but neither reflexive nor transitive is the relation $R$ such that $R =\{\}$. This I think is correct because both symmetry and anti-symmetry are "if...then" statements and if the "if" is false, then it is vacuously true meaning that $\{\}$ is symmetric and anti-symmetric

I also have another answer that goes as $R = \{(A,A), (B,B)\}$. This second answer is because I interpreted neither.. nor as not ($A$ or $B$) which is not $A$ and not $B$. So, I only had to make sure it is not reflexive to make the second part false (since symmetry and anti-symmetry imply transitivity)

Which of my answers are correct please. If none, can anyone give a correct answer

Comment: What do you mean by a relation "that follows the exact terms above"?  I don't see any terms that define a relation...I just see a set with three elements.

Comment: @lulu I meant it in reference to the question but you are right, that was unclear. So I edited it

Comment: Got it. Your proposed relations are transitive, somewhat vacuously.  That is to say, there are no counterexamples to transitivity in the empty relation, for example.

Comment: @lulu I see. So any example I give has to counter both of them? I thought that I could counter one. That means I can't make a relation that counters both which means such a relation does not exist which then means, I have to prove it false by proving its negation. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I suggest trying to argue that the relation does not exist.  Indeed, In order to not be transitive there needs to be some non-trivial similarity $X\sim Y$ with $X\neq Y$.  And then symmetry requires that $Y\sim X$ but anti-symmetry forbids that.

Comment: @lulu Also, I wrote the negation as If a relation on S is symmetric and antisymmetric, then it is transitive or reflexive. Is that correct?

Comment: Well...I'd say, more simply, that "symmetric plus anti-symmetric implies transitive."  I don't think reflexivity enters into it.

Comment: @lulu Okay. That makes sense. Thank you very much